# Page reloading on POST request using fetch

Tags: javascript, html, post, fetch

I'm trying to make a post request to a node.js Server to submit some data to the server using Fetch API. Now I want to ***display a success message*** according to the response sent back by the server, but I'm unable to do so as the page refreshes itself every time I try to do so. I've tried many different ways to stop this (eg. e.preventDefault(), changing button to div, changing the type of button to button instead of submit) but nothing seems to work. Please someone help me out. Posting both my HTML as well as Javascript code here. Also I'm very new to web development (experience of 2 months only), so please can you also tell me is the method I'm following is right or wrong. Thanks!

I'm using Semantic UI for the css part

**HTML code**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ui fixed inverted menu">
        <div class="ui container">
            <a href="#" class="header item">
                  My Project
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui main text container">
        <form class="ui loading form" id="main_form">
            <div class="field">
                <textarea name="message" id="otp_message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="ui success message">
                <div class="header">OTP Sent</div>
                <p>You've successfully sent the OTP on Mobile Number</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ui center aligned grid container">
                <div class="ui row">
                    <button type="submit" class="ui green button" id="btn_validate">Send</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<!-- <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

<script src="./scripts/send_message.js"></script>

</html>
```

**Javascript**:

```
let id;
let otp;
function processUser() {
    const parameters = location.search.substring(1);
    id = (parameters.split("=")[1]);
    let url = 'http://localhost:3030/ShowContacts?id=';
    url += id;
    let data;
    fetch(url, {method:"GET"})
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 404) throw new Error('User not found');
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(response => {
        data = JSON.parse(response);
        // document.getElementById('name').innerText += ' ' + jsonDATA.first_name + ' ' + jsonDATA.last_name;
        // document.getElementById('phone_number').innerText += ' ' + jsonDATA.mobile_number;
        generateOTP();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
}
processUser();
async function generateOTP() {
    let url = 'http://localhost:3030/getOTP';
    fetch(url, { method: "GET" })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 404) throw new Error('Unable to generate otp');
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(response => {
        const jsonDATA = JSON.parse(response);
        otp = jsonDATA.otp;
        document.getElementById('main_form').classList.remove('loading');
        document.getElementById('otp_message').value = `Hi. Your OTP is: ${otp} . Please do not share it with anybody else.`;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e.message);
    })
}

const myForm = document.getElementById('main_form');
// const btn = document.getElementById('btn_validate');

document.forms['main_form'].addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let otpSent = false;
    const message = document.getElementById('otp_message').value;
    const raw = JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
        message: message,
        otp: otp
    });
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: raw
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:3030/otpSent";
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        otpSent =  response.success;
        if (otpSent) {
            let prevClassValue = myForm.getAttribute('class');
            prevClassValue += " success";
            myForm.setAttribute('class', prevClassValue);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
})
```

Comment: Coz its a form with button type submit

Comment: @RahulPadalkar I also tried to use div instead of that, no benefit

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Put `return false` at the end of the event handling function.

Comment: @Thevs Thanks man! that works, but why wasn'.t the event.preventDefault() thing not working? And is it a good practice to return false like this?

Comment: @Priyadarshan Vijay `preventDefault()` works only for real DOM events. `submit` is a 'virtual' event.

Comment: Oh okay! Cheers @Thevs :)

Answer (score 2):

It was due to Live Server, which also looking for changes in .json file. You can fix it by changing Live Server's Setting: Go to Extension tab in VS code and look for Live Server and then click on the "Setting" icon and then click on "Extension Setting" and then scroll down to and click on "edit in settings.json" under "Live Server > Setting :Ignore Files" and then replace and add:

```
{

...rest of the code

"liveServer.settings.ignoreFiles": [
  "**/*.json"
  ".vscode/**",
  "**/*.scss",
  "**/*.sass",
  "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had next code:

```
    const loginHandler = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const data = await login({...form})
    }
```

Where login is a function from my custom hook, but simplier, it just send info on exact url by fetch. By the way, i understood, that page refreshing, it's just common behavior of form with button. So I add event.preventDefault() before fetch (it's important).

In your case you have from with button too, and refreshing goes accordingly to this.

```
 1. Add onClickHandler

    const submitHandler = async(event) => {
        event.preventDefault()
       ...logic
    }

 2. Connect this handler to button

 <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler} class="ui green button" id="btn_validate">Send</button>
```